Add editable text of number of concurent threads in layout
I want a text/integer box that shows this value:

So that I can see the value and change it at a glance.
Mockup:

Alternatively, a button that would get me to this exact menu. I always forget the path.
What I tried
I ran through these settings/customizations, but I didn't find it:

I already changed some layout, such as hiding rebuild in a submenu to prevent accidental clicks:

But I don't know where to start with this one.

As a workaround, you can simply type Maximum concurrent c++ compilations in .vssettings file to get the path of this option. The .vssettings file can be exported from Tools->Import and Export settings.


Alternatively, a button that would get me to this exact menu. I always forget the path.

Based on my test, it is not supported to customize Maximum concurrent c++ compilations in menu bar in VS2019.
However, here are some ideas you can check:
1.You can add a menu Maximum concurrent c++ compilations and add the path as a reminder in the name. And you  will see this new menu in the Menu bar.
Tools->Options->Projects and Solutions-> VC++ Project Settings.


2 Consider creating a VSIX project that has a custom command item template.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/adding-a-menu-to-the-visual-studio-menu-bar?view=vs-2022#create-a-vsix-project-that-has-a-custom-command-item-template
